# Removing tables, shapes and images from .doc file

Tags: c#, parsing, text

I am parsing a .doc file in C# for extracting text.

The problem is that the .doc file has tables, shapes and images, as well as my text. I use Microsoft Interop Word library for extracting text. When I extract the text I also get the labels on shapes and images, and the data which is inside the columns and rows of table.

I don't need the labels of shapes or data from tables or images. How can I remove these shapes, their labels and images and tables from my .doc file?

This is code.

```
public void ReadMsWord()
    {
        // variable to store file path
        string filePath = null;
        // open dialog box to select file
        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
        // dilog box title name
        file.Title = "Word File";
        // set initial directory of computer system
        file.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        // set restore directory
        file.RestoreDirectory = true;

        // execute if block when dialog result box click ok button
        if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // store selected file path
            filePath = file.FileName.ToString();
        }

        try
        {
            // create word application
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
            // create object of missing value
            object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            // create object of selected file path
            object path = filePath;
            // set file path mode
            object readOnly = false;
            // open document                
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
            // select whole data from active window document
            docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
            // handover the data to cllipboard
            docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
            // clipboard create reference of idataobject interface which transfer the data
            IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            //set data into richtextbox control in text format
            string t = "";
            string[] y = {};
            t = data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
            y = t.Split('\n');
            string check = "";
            string check1 = "";
            string A = "";
            //int i = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < y.Length - 1; i++)
            {

                if (!Regex.IsMatch(y[i], @"^([A|B|C|D]|  )")&&(y[i].Length>15))
                {
                    //@"^\d+"
                    //int j = i + 1;
                    //  while (!Regex.IsMatch(asdf[j], @"^[A|B|C]"))
                    // {

                    check = check + '\n'+'\n' + y[i];    
                     //i++;

                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < y.Length - 1; i++)
            {

                if (Regex.IsMatch(y[i], @"^[A |B |C |D ]"))
                {
                    //@"^\d+"
                    //int j = i + 1;
                    //  while (!Regex.IsMatch(asdf[j], @"^[A|B|C]"))
                    // {


                    check1 = check1 + '\n' + '\n' + y[i];
                    //i++;

                }
            }
```

Code For @theGhostofc this is the code which i am using and which is giving exception type mis match type

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    

    string filePath = null;
        // open dialog box to select file
        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
        // dilog box title name
        file.Title = "Word File";
        // set initial directory of computer system
        file.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        // set restore directory
        file.RestoreDirectory = true;

        // execute if block when dialog result box click ok button
        if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // store selected file path
            filePath = file.FileName.ToString();
        }









       try
       {
           // create word application
           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new   

           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
              // create object of missing value
           object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
           // create object of selected file path
           object path = filePath;
           // set file path mode
           object readOnly = false;
           // open document                
           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path,
            ref miss, ref readOnly,
                                                               ref miss, 

          ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,

                                                                             ref miss, 
          ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,

                                                                             ref miss, 
          ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                                                                             ref miss);
           foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table tbl in docs.Tables)
           {
               tbl.Delete();
           }
           foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shp in docs.Shapes)
           {
               shp.Delete();
           }
           foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape ilshp in 
            docs.InlineShapes)
           {
               if (ilshp.Type == 
                  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture)
                   ilshp.Delete();



           }
           docs.Close(ref path,ref readOnly,ref miss);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
}
```

Code for @theghostofc

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // variable to store file path
        string filePath = null;
        // open dialog box to select file
        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
        // dilog box title name
        file.Title = "Word File";
        // set initial directory of computer system
        file.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        // set restore directory
        file.RestoreDirectory = true;

        // execute if block when dialog result box click ok button
        if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // store selected file path
            filePath = file.FileName.ToString();
        }
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
        // create object of missing value
        object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        // create object of selected file path
        object path = filePath;
        // set file path mode
        object readOnly = false;
        // open document                
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss,
                                                                          ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                                                                          ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                                                                          ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
        try
        {
            // create word application


            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table tbl in docs.Tables)
            {
                tbl.Delete();
            }
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shp in docs.Shapes)
            {
                shp.Delete();
            }
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape ilshp in docs.InlineShapes)
            {
                if (ilshp.Type == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture)
                    ilshp.Delete();
            }
            object saveOption = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
            object originalFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdOriginalFormat.wdOriginalDocumentFormat;
            object routeDocument = false;
            docs.Close(ref saveOption, ref originalFormat, ref routeDocument);

            // docs.Close(ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
            docs = null;
            GC.Collect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

This is the code please tell me also these both methods ask for parameteres `docs.Save()` and `docs.Close()` . I have passed the parametres to `docs.Close()` but i dont know what parameters should be passed to `docs.Save()`  so i did'nt use `docs.Save()` in my code so plz define me explicitly these things i will be very glad of you

Comment: Can you share some piece of code which you have written?

Comment: I have share the code for u @theghostofc

Comment: Try docs.Context.Text, or take a look at [this library](http://sourceforge.net/p/word-reader/wiki/Home/) (you won't even need Word!).

Comment: This is i think not the solution or nearer to solution @CodeCaster.

Comment: And I think it is. Can you explain why you think that will not help? Or, what kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: Yes but this library is use for extracting the raw text for which u have told about and i am already extracting the text.With due respect please read the question again.

Comment: With all due respect try to read the link I posted: _"It can currently extract only the raw text from a .doc or .docx file."_ So it will give you the text without shapes and images, which is easier than removing them like you are trying to do now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30528/discussion-between-jahanzaib-jahanzaib-and-codecaster)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all you want is to remove tables, shapes and images from the word doc, you may try the following code snippet:

```
try
{
    // create word application
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
    // create object of missing value
    object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    // create object of selected file path
    object path = filePath;
    // set file path mode
    object readOnly = false;
    // open document                
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table tbl in docs.Tables)
    {
        tbl.Delete();
    }
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shp in docs.Shapes)
    {
        shp.Delete();
    }
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape ilshp in docs.InlineShapes)
    {
        if (ilshp.Type == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture)
            ilshp.Delete();
    }
    docs.Close();
}
```

You may save `docs` once you're done.

If you want to remove more objects, you may see more options with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdInlineShapeType` which would allow removing **Linked Pictures** too.

> P.S.: This is not a copy-paste code. Please use this as a starting point only.

Comment: plz also tell me how to save the doc after processing Thanks.

Comment: and this code is not working giving the error type miss match @theghostofc

Comment: The solution is not to remove all non-text objects from the obtained input, but to only get text in the first place.

Comment: @jahanzaibjahanzaib try to read the answer again: _" P.S.: This is not a copy-paste code. Please use this as a starting point only"_.

Comment: @jahanzaibjahanzaib `ApplicationClass()` was not working for me, so I tried with `Application()`, which worked. To save the document, you may use `docs.Save();` or `docs.SaveAs();` whichever suits your purpose.

Comment: @theghostofc it is still not working after changing the `Applicationclass()` to `Application()` only.

Comment: @jahanzaibjahanzaib, this is strange. I started by using your code, and major modification is after `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs ...` line. Could you paste the code that you have currently?

Comment: @jahanzaibjahanzaib, if you're done, please mark answer for other fellow StackOverflow members.

Comment: @theghostofc on this page i had not found any solution from any one and thank you for try to help me

Comment: @theghostofc i am reconsidering your code for some issues but the code is running but it isn't bring any change after saving the document or may be it wont saving the document. reply me soon plz

Comment: @jahanzaibjahanzaib, I just did a `docs.Save();` before `docs.Close();` and it works fine for me. I am able to see the changes to the Word document. Check for permissions issue, if any. If you're not able to see the saved changes, please share what you're trying to implement

Comment: but `docs.Save` asks for parameter so what parametre should i pass?

Comment: no one is helping plz help and i dont think that i have asked a very difficult question.....    :(

Comment: @jahanzaibjahanzaib, `docs.Save()` would not ask for a parameter. `docs.SaveAs()` would ask for parameters. Could you share your code please?

Comment: @theghostofc i have already shared the code please see the last edit of the question.

Comment: @theghostofc i am very thankful to u u have helped me alot but the code which u have shared above is just removing images and tables not the labels of images that is also a lot but can u help me a little more to also remvoe the labels of images so i  accept your answer as accepted answer.